# Uploading the Image in the ImageView from Gallery or through Camera

Tags: java, android

I am trying this code. It's letting the image getting uploaded for gallery part but giving an error for camera part.

The error is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null
>   object reference`

Code:

```
public class MyProfile extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

 //This is the unique id which represents the id has been selected
 private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


ImageView profilePic;
Button buttonToUpload;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_profile, container, false);

    buttonToUpload = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.upload_button);
    profilePic = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile);

    buttonToUpload.setOnClickListener(this);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    CharSequence choice[] = {"Gallery", "Camera"};
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialog.setTitle("Choose").
            setItems(choice, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(which == 0){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        //When the user selects a picture the result of which image is selected by the user is given by startActiviytForResult
                        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

                    }else {
                        //If User chooses to upload photo through camera
                         Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                         startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                    }
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();

}

/**
 * Receive the result from a previous call to
 * {@link #startActivityForResult(Intent, int)}.  This follows the
 * related Activity API as described there in
 * {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)}.
 *
 * @param requestCode The integer request code originally supplied to
 *                    startActivityForResult(), allowing you to identify who this
 *                    result came from.
 * @param resultCode The integer result code returned by the child activity
 *                   through its setResult().
 * @param data An Intent, which can return result data to the caller
 *               (various data can be attached to Intent "extras").
 */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        //Checking that the gallery intent has called this method
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            //Uniform Resource Indicator: This shows us the image in the form that has been selected

           Uri selectedImage = data.getData();



            profilePic.setImageURI(selectedImage);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }

  }
}
```

Comment: `//Checking that the gallery intent has called this method`. But you are not doing that as you use `requestCode RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE` for both intents. You should separate them. Handle them differently.

Comment: Your error message does not match your code, as you are not calling a `get()` method anywhere in the code. We cannot help you unless you provide a [mcve], with a full stack trace and the code that triggers your crash. Also note that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not supposed to return a `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE is not supposed to return a Uri then what should I use ??

Comment: Since you are not providing `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, your photo will be a small `Bitmap` available via `data.getParcelableExtra("data")`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hey thanks for help..Can you help me in one more thing...Have you seen any notepad app..when we create a new file and after writing some notes when we press the back button the file gets saved and gets displayed in the dashboard..How can i make this save feature..? I have searched but only got the idea of saving the edit text content in a string and then loading back